# How do I change my sql statement WHERE clause based on drop down selection

Tags: reporting-services

I know this is a newbie question but I need to know how to dynamically change the WHERE clause in a SQL statement based on a drop down selection.

I have a list of supervisors in a drop down.  I know how to use each one individually using the parameter, but how do I change the SQL when they select the ALL option?

Comment: You need a scripting language such as php or javascript to do that. Which scripting language are you planning on using to do this? If you want I can tell how to do it in php if your interested.

Comment: Do you mean "SQL Server Reporting Services"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a *multivalue parameter*. The basic steps for setting this up:

1. Create a dataset for selecting the Key and Label for available supervisors.
2. Create a parameter `@SupervisorIDs` with the first dataset as available values.
3. Set the parameter to "Allow multiple values".
4. Create your second dataset that retrieves the actual results
5. In the second dataset, create a filter like this: `WHERE SuperVisorId IN (@SupervisorIDs)`

Reporting services will replace the parameter inside the WHERE clause dynamically with a comma seperated list with the values your user has selected, before sending the query to SQL Server.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for more (detailed) info on the subject.

Comment: @andycicchillo How can i eliminate where condition if all values are selected Is any way to do this in SSRS [using latest version 2016 now]